# How do i create menu in base toolbar?

Tags: c#, arcgis-engine, arcgis-9.3

i'd like to create menus in a base toolbar like arcHdro tools or spatial analyst . how can i create menus with arcengine 9.3 in my toolbar ( the toolbar shows in arcmap )?

Answer (score 3):

I solved it . first create a base toolbar in arcengine . then create a base menu and add base menu with  additem method .for example additem("myproject.mybasemenu") in the base toolbar .you can add your commands in the base menu and then use this instruction .
for more detail ... [see this link](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/dotnet/9ee2d74d-06ee-4a7e-b848-c93beead1d4c.htm)